# Assign variable value within select, among other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am aware that you can assign a value to a variable within a select by going

```
SELECT @blahBlah = (tbl.ProductGroup) 
FROM tbl
```

Ok, now what I need to do is as follow.

Each account/user has a set number of transactions allowed every day; eg. Account 1 can do 5 transactions and Account 2 can do 3.

So in a select that will determine whether this account has overshot its limit and by how many, we have numerous `inSelect` calculations to produce column data.

The problem is that we now have about 4 columns that will each do a nested select to get the limits from another table, in order to produce a value for the current one.

What would be ideal is to assign these limits to a `@variable` in the select statement and to only reference that variable within said statement if needed.

To give a brief example (not actual logic):

```
SELECT
  @Limit = (SELECT Limit From tClient Where tClient.clientId = tbl.ClientId),
  (select count(*) from batch where batchItemCount > @limit) AS BadBatches,
  ....
FROM TBL
```

You get the picture.

Is there some method to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [Common Table Expression(CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do these sort of things. The following is the basic idea that you can tweak to get it work for your case:

```
;WITH limtis AS
(
   SELECT Limit, ClientId
   From tClient 
   Where tClient.clientId = tbl.ClientId
)
select ...
from batch
INNER JOIN Limtis On ...
WHERE ...
```

Hope you got the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select clientid from tClient as t1 inner join batch as t2
 on t1.clientId=t2.clientId
 group by clientId
 having sum(batchItemCount)>sum(limit)
```